# Rotate brackets until they're balanced

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string

Take the string of brackets `]][][[`. When you rotate it to the right once, you get `[]][][`. If you rotate it again, you get `[[]][]`. All brackets in this string are balanced.

**The Task:**

Your program (or function) will be given a string of brackets, represented in any reasonable format (including using other things in place of the brackets, like `-1` and `1`). The numbers of opening and closing brackets will always be equal, so `[` or `][]` won't be given as inputs.

Output should be a rotation of those brackets which is balanced. You can check this by repeatedly removing pairs of brackets (`[]`). With a balanced string of brackets, none will be left over.

Rotating a string to the right involves taking the last character, and moving it to the beginning. For example, `01234567` rotated right 3 times would be `56701234`. The direction of rotation doesn't matter, but no brackets should be added, discarded, mirrored, etc. If multiple solutions are possible, such as `[][[]]` or `[[]][]`, you can return any of them.

**Test Cases:**

```
[]          ->  []
]][[        ->  [[]]
[][]][      ->  [[][]]
][][[]      ->  [[]][] OR [][[]]
[[[][][]]]  ->  [[[][][]]]
]]][][][[[  ->  [[[]]][][] OR [][[[]]][] OR [][][[[]]]
```

**Other:**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes per language wins!

Comment: Can I return all valid answers?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Sure, that's fine.

Comment: Can I use {} instead of []?

Comment: @Ausername Sure, you're allowed to use other stuff in place of the brackets.

Comment: May I return the number of rotation instead of the result of rotation?

Comment: Now I'm wondering if it's possible for this to have no solution.

Comment: Okay, it seems that Leo's answer proves that this is always possible.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what on earth "rotation" meant.  And I still don't get why you call this operation rotation.  You really should explain what this means.

Comment: @WheatWizard "Rotation" seems to be a pretty common name for this, although I'll add an explanation of what I mean.

Comment: @xigoi I'm 99% sure all inputs can be solved. For any input, imagine replacing any already balanced parts with a `.`. The example input would become `]].[[`. You'll always end up with `/]*[*/`, with some dots interwoven occasionally. You can always then rotate that to be `/[*]*/`, which is balanced.

Comment: @tsh I'd say that's not allowed, I think it's too different from the other allowed output methods

Comment: Here's a proof:  Replace `[` with +1 and `]` with -1.  Consider instead of a string as a ring of these integers.  Choose an arbitrary point and starting with zero pass around the ring adding each integer to the sum.  (this will return to zero).  If the sum never goes below 0 you are fine, if it does choose the minimum point and start from there instead.  Now it will never go below zero, so that is where you begin / end the string.

Comment: @WheatWizard rotate is a common name for this operation. some processors have instruction level support for it, ex. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate#Rotate_Instructions

Answer (score 17):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
ṙ¹η◄∫
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkPuoqfHQNi6FXA1FpehYpUN7H7VN0nzU1JSr8ahtgoutevT/hztnHtp5bvuj6S2POlb///8/OpYrNjY6mis6NhpIcwHJaKBQdDSIDxQByYJZQBEkJgA)

No loops, no recursion, just a straightforward simple operation. Encodes `[` as `1` and `]` as `-1`.

```
ṙ¹η◄∫
ṙ¹       Rotate the list left by
  η        the (1-based) index
   ◄         of the minimum
    ∫      in the list of cumulative sums
```

This comes from observing that the list of cumulative sums will have a minimum at the point where the most closed brackets are preceding open brackets. By moving all the previous brackets to the end, we can guarantee that there won't be any prefix containing more closed than open brackets.

---

### Previous answer, 7 bytes

```
Ωȯ¬▼∫ṙ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq6GoFB2rdGjvo7ZJmo@aGnM1HrVNcLFVj/5/buWJ9YfWPJq251HH6oc7Zxr@//9fKTY2NhoEo6OVAA)

Encodes `[` as `1` and `]` as `-1`, following [HyperNeutrino's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221295/62393) to use the cumulative sum, but then uses an additional observation:

Since we are working with an equal number of open and closed brackets, the total sum will always be `0`. If at any point the string is unbalanced, the cumulative sum at that point will be negative. From this, we can say that a string will be balanced if the minimum of its cumulative sum is exactly `0`.

```
Ω(¬▼∫)ṙ1
      ṙ1    Rotate by 1
Ω           until
   ▼         the minimum
    ∫        of the cumulative sums
  ¬          is 0
```

Comment: A [similar approach in Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221304/66833) comes out at 4 bytes as Jelly has a builtin for "Index of maximal elements"

Answer (score 11):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>42</s> 34 bytes

```perl6
{({S/.//~$/}...{try !.EVAL}).tail}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1qjOlhfT1@/TkW/Vk9Pr7qkqFJBUc81zNGnVlOvJDEzp/Z/cWKlQppCXa5@TLCWvkJafpFCTmZeavH/6FgFONC1U1CIjuWKjY2ORhGKjo3lio4FktEogiBhIBENMwKmFsj3D1IASwD1gRUCWbEwBTA@0B4wKxpkG0wKIgTTD@FDeVA@AA)

In Raku, a set of balanced square brackets is entirely valid syntax, so we can simply rotate the string until it `EVAL`s successfully, and take the last element.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                }  # Anonymous codeblock taking a string
  {S/.//   }                        # Remove the first character
        ~$/                         # And add it to the end
 (          ...            )        # Repeat until
               {try !.EVAL}            # The program can be eval'd
                                       # This returns ![] (true) if successful
                            .tail   # Return the last element
```

I thought [this 31 byte program](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/79YX0NPS1NDT1NfxVDFQL80ryQzR6GkqFJBUc81zNHn///oWK7Y2OhorujYaCDNBSSjgULR0SA@UAQkC2YBRf7lF5Rk5ucV/9ctAAA) using the `-p` flag would work, but either TIO is too outdated or Raku has some sort of weird behaviour about `until`/`while` and `$_`. Until I can test it using the latest version, you can check it [like so](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n5ZfpKCRk5mXWqypoGunoJKoUM2lEq9gC2RZ/y/W19DT0tTQ09RXMVQx0C/NK8nMUSgpqlRQ1HMNc/T5b81VnFipoBLPVfs/OpYrNjY6mis6NhpIcwHJaKBQdDSIDxQByYJZQBEA).

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ÄMṙ@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wi@/DnTMd/ts@apgb@3DHkkcNMw@3P2qY4fFwd/ejxn2x0ZH//yvFxsZGg2B0tBIA)

Similar approach to [Leo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221300/66833), give that an upvote!

Uses `-1` and `1` for `[` and `]` and returns all valid rotations

By swapping the signs from Leo's approach, we can operate on the maximal elements, rather than minimal, as Jelly has a builtin `M` to return the indices of maximal elements, thus saving a byte

### How it works

```
ÄMṙ@ - Main link. Takes a list of 1 and -1, A
Ä    - Take the cumulative sums
 M   - Yield the indices of the maximal elements
  ṙ@ - Rotate A that many times for each index
```

Comment: beat me to it :(

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 69 bytes

```python
def f(s):
 try:exec s.replace(')','),');print s
 except:f(s[1:]+s[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoMwEEX3OcXgJn@olOoyPYq4kHRCC2JDkoWePo61LQzMvP/nxa0830tf60MCBWR2hkranKziKV@TxHnyAsu2taxzj@m1FMqGZPUSi1Nn6Nx4ycNt5BrQgBs2upmB8wJD4Zsq/D6Ao9Hub3wQh1d3)

Tried a similar approach to *Jo King*'s Raku answer by evaluating the bracket string, only difference being an added `,` after every `)` so that the expression is valid.

Takes `(` and `)` instead of `[` and `]`.

*-2 bytes thanks to Sisyphus, -3 bytes thanks to dingledooper*

[51 bytes if it's allowed to take ( and ), instead of ( and )](https://tio.run/##TYwxDoAgEAR7XnGx2osUaolPMVZ6RBslQKGvR9Bo7HZn586dcdm3LqVZLFkENoqiP40cMlHonV@3SEGRHJO4aLIxtGasw9CMnCwqsK5Y5cCaNfDkDHH3dyrgM4Fnv5X/@UtR/qQL)

Comment: Cool eval approach! Also [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoMwEEX3OcXgJn@olOoyPYq4kHRCC2JDkoWePo61LQzMvP/nxa0830tf60MCBWR2hkranKziKV@TxHnyAsu2taxzj@m1FMqGZPUSi1Nn6Nx4ycNt5BrQgBs2upmB8wJD4Zsq/D6Ao9Hub3wQh1d3).

Comment: 69 bytes. Nice.

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
until(all(>0).scanl(+)1)$drop<>take$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NDoIwEITvPMUeOLSREnsHTl55AuSw4Ucbl7ah6@tbhQQlarLJ7peZzcwVw20gimbybmY4IWNeO@tMD0IUlZTJWJ7j3bIhgUSiOso8dGhJHKSWaT87X1SMtyHVkYfAAUpoGp2B0m0GjVqvDJZZ@INvZbPtnNv3Dr@X@olQ/6xrQJskExr7ajahr8HPxjKkC8AIa@n46EbCS4iq8/4J)

*Saved 2 bytes using `<>`.*

Takes in a list of 1's and -1's. Actually pretty readable:

```hs
until            until
 (all(>0).       we get all positive values from
  scanl(+)1)     the cumulative sums of the list starting from 1,
 $drop<>take     rotate the list
 $1              by 1
```

The `drop<>take` rotates by using `<>` to concatenate the list with elements `drop`ped from the start and the list with that many elements `take`n from the start. The `(<>)` is imported in the TIO link but is available in base starting with 8.4.1; [see this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177774/20260). We could also do `tail<>take 1` for the same length.

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

[This algorithm.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221304/43319)

Anonymous prefix lambda, taking `-1` for `[` and `1` for `]`.

```apl
{⍵⌽⍨⊃⍒+\⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79ZHPXsf9a541NX8qHeSdgxQoPZ/2qO2CY96@4Bih9YbP2qb@KhvanCQM5AM8fAM/l9QlAqUP7TeUEs9Wt32UdciroL84hKgULV6tEKserSRNtCQ2FqwqEKaAlC5gnp0rDoKPzY2OlodTUU0UBBNFVAQXWd0NEglUC2GiWDhaJC5XJr5aWlcXNGxCnCga6egEB3LBbIXRQhoEBfEahRBkDDEdlS1QL5/kAJYAqgP7hSYAhifC@EahBRECKYfwofyoHwA) ([This template](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221298/43319))

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`:

`+\⍵` cumulative sum of the argument

`⍒` indices that would sort that descending (i.e. index of the largest, index of the next-largest, etc.)

`⊃` the first of that (i.e. the index of the largest)

`⍵⌽⍨` use that to rotate the argument to the left

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ṙJÄ-eƊÐḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpleh1t0U491HZ7wcMf8/7aPGuZGP9yx5FHDzMPtjxpmeDzc3f2ocV90bOT//0qxsbHRIBgdrQQA)

-2 bytes thanks to ChartZ Belatedly + 1 byte saved from being allowed to return all valid configurations instead of just one

### Explanation

```
ṙJÄ-eƊÐḟ  Main Link
ṙ         Rotate by
 J        [1, 2, ..., len(input)]
      Ðḟ  Filter: keep all elements where the following is falsy (in this case, a list of all zeroes):
  Ä       Cumulative Sum
    e     equal to (vectorize)
   -      -1
```

Basically, keep all arrangements where the cumulative sum is never equal to -1 (clever observation from ChartZ that since the cumsum changes by 1 each time and starts at 0, if any value is negative, then there must be a -1 somewhere, so rather than doing `<0$` we can do `-e`. and then also that the filter quick accepts a list of zeroes as falsy so I don't have to use the `any` atom)

Comment: I've tried golfing this myself but I don't know Jelly well enough: isn't it possible (and wouldn't it be shorter) to code it like `while(any of the cumulative sum is negative)(rotate by 1)`?

Comment: @Leo Probably not; the way Jelly handles while loops, and the value that each part of the loop handles, is often difficult to make short

Comment: @Leo Your idea saved me 10 bytes in my J answer.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpleh1t0U491HZ7wcMf8/7aPGuZGP9yx5FHDzMPtjxpmeDzc3f2ocV90bOT//0qxsbHRIBgdrQQA)

Comment: [Also 8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wi2Hqw50zHQ5tPTzB57/to4a5sQ93LHnUMPNw@6OGGR4Pd3c/atwXG/3/v1JsbGw0CEZHKwEA), porting @Jonah's J answer (uses `-1` for open brackets)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly Oh, clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,t=1:s*all((t:=t+n)for n in s)or f(s[1:]+s[:1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBCsMgEETv/Yo9ro0ell6K4JeIB0sjEawRtS39emtDaEPosrDz2JlJrzrN8XROuTWngr1drhYKr4pkOdoQEKtUdYjMzRki@AiFdeWwaJJmKFqSYe05@TACyZR9rOhwfNiAPqZ7RdanaeIgyBy0WASHz3b80fexmja@Nbqh/RH7evHPubS/AQ)

Takes in a list of 1's and -1's.

Comment: Oh, this newly introduced me to the ":=" syntax. Very useful for some code golfing tasks.

Comment: @Emil Yup, see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180041/20260) for some more ideas on using it.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
(⊢⌽⍨1∊+\)⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NR16JHPXsf9a4wfNTRpR2j@ah38aPOhf/THrVNeNTb96ir@dB640dtEx/1TQ0OcgaSIR6ewf8LilKB8ofWG2qpR6vbAo3gKsgvLgEKVatHK8SqRxtpP@rdGlsLFlVIUwAqV1CPjlVH4cfGRkero6mIBgqiqQIKouuMjgapBKrFMBEsHA0yl0szPy2Niys6VgEOdO0UFKJjuUD2oggBDeKCWI0iCBKG2I6qFsj3D1IASwD1wZ0CUwDjcyFcg5CCCMH0Q/hQHpQPAA)

An APL port of [Jonah's golfed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221296/78410), which in turn uses [Leo's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221293/rotate-brackets-until-theyre-balanced#comment514707_221295). Like Jonah's, the input is `-1` for `[` and `1` for `]`.

#### How it works

```apl
(⊢⌽⍨1∊+\)⍣≡  ⍝ Input: a vector of -1s and 1s, -1 for open and 1 for close
(...)⍣≡  ⍝ Repeat until it does not change...
1∊+\     ⍝   1 if cumulative sum has a 1, 0 otherwise
⊢⌽⍨      ⍝   Rotate left ^ times (so it stops when the above result is zero)
```

Comment: See my last idea which shaved off 2 more bytes for me, and may help your APL answer too.  (EDIT: looks like some of the other answers had this idea too...)

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>40 29 19 18 15 14</sup> 13 bytes

```
|.~1+0{&\:+/\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/a/TqDLUNqtVirLT1Y/5rcpWkFpfY6imkJmfkO2joWqVpqmnEG2qrRyvEqmfqxWpycXGpR8eqK4CUKYBYQG50LFwgNjY6GiKEJAjmgIVjUdSCuWDVIBVAGYQOhAhYVyxIANmWWKig@n8A)

<sup>-11 after applying HyperNeutrino's scan sum idea</sup>

<sup>-10 after reading Leo's comment to HyperNeutrino: `while(any of the cumulative sum is negative)(rotate by 1)`</sup>

<sup>-3 thanks to a clever observation by Bubbler</sup>

Takes input as a list of integers, where `[ = _1` and `] = 1` -- reversing the more natural order saves 1 byte.

### how

- `|.~` Rotate by...
- `1+` 1 plus...
- `0{` the first element of...
- `\:` the grade down of...
- `+/\` the scan sum.

That is, take the index of the max element of the scan sum, add one to it, and rotate by that amount.

Comment: -1 with repeat-bind trick: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NQzVavTqDBVS9bT1YzTjrOL/a3KVpBaX2OoppCZn5Dto6FqlaappxBtqq0crxKpn6sVqcnGpR8eqK4BUKYBYQG50LFwgNjY6GiKEJAjmgIVjUdSCuWDVIBVAGYQOhAhYVyxIANmWWKig@n8A "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Actually you can just use the test itself as the rotate count, so it is [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWr06gwVUvW09WM046zi/2tylaQWl9jqKaQmZ@Q7aOhapWmqacQbaqtHK8SqZ@rFanJxqUfHqiuAVCmAWEBudCxcIDY2OhoihCQI5oCFY1HUgrlg1SAVQBmEDoQIWFcsSADZlliooPp/AA).

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 bytes

```perl
$_=chop.$_ while s/<(?R)*>//gr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jY5I79ATyVeoTwjMydVoVjfRsM@SFPLTl8/vej/fxs7Ljs7GxsuGzsbIM0FJG2AQjY2ID5QBCQLZgFF/uUXlGTm5xX/1y3IAQA)

Uses `<>` as the bracket delimiters.

The regex `s/<(?R)*>//gr` recursively substitutes bracket patterns with the empty string, and instead of mutating the string returns the final value. If this is empty, then all our brackets are fully matched and since the empty string is falsy, the loop stops. Else we rotate the string one using the construction `$_=chop.$_`.

-1 thanks to [Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings) by replacing the ugly `s/.//,$_.=$&` with the much more elegant `$_=chop.$_`.

Comment: Nice! I was hoping to find a way to use `while!eval` but I can't come up with a combination of chars that works... You can save 1 byte though, using `$_=chop.$_`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jY5I79ATyVeoTwjMydVoVjfRsM@SFPLTl8/vej/fxs7Ljs7GxsuGzsbIM0FJG2AQjY2ID5QBCQLZgFF/uUXlGTm5xX/1y3IAQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings That's a nice improvement!

Answer (score 6):

## Scratch 3.0, 49 blocks/407 bytes

[image: pain]

As SB Syntax:

```
define C
set[T v]to(0
set[i v]to(1
set[Y v]to(1
repeat(length of[S v
if<(item(i)of[S v])=[a]>then
set[T v]to((T)+(1
else
set[T v]to((T)-(1
end
if<(T)<(0)>then
set[Y v]to(0)
end
set[i v]to((i)+(1
define(s
set[i v]to(1
repeat(length of(s
add(letter(i)of(s))to[S v]
set[i v]to((i)+(1
end
C
repeat until<(Y)=(1
set[t v]to(item(length of[S v])of[S v]
delete(length of[S v])of[S v
insert(t)at(1)of[S v
C
end
say(S
```

Because rotating a string in Scratch/bracket matching is a really good idea. Use `a` for opening brackets and `b` for closing brackets.

### Explained

```
define C -- Helper function used for checking if the brackets are balanced
set[T v]to(0   
set[i v]to(1 --- T = running tally, i = string index, Y = return value
set[Y v]to(1
repeat(length of[S v
if<(item(i)of[S v])=[a]>then
set[T v]to((T)+(1
else                 ---- Opening brackets (a) increment the tally by 1. Closing brackets (b) decrement the tally by 1. If the brackets are balanced, this tally will never go below 0, as the brackets will cancel each other out
set[T v]to((T)-(1
end
if<(T)<(0)>then
set[Y v]to(0)
end
set[i v]to((i)+(1

define(s --- Main function
set[i v]to(1
repeat(length of(s
add(letter(i)of(s))to[S v] --- Place every character of the input into a list
set[i v]to((i)+(1
end
C ---- Check if the inital input is balanced
repeat until<(Y)=(1
set[t v]to(item(length of[S v])of[S v]  --- Rotate the string once
delete(length of[S v])of[S v
insert(t)at(1)of[S v
C   ---------- And check each rotation
end
say(S
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>([c,...r]=a).some(v=>(c+=v)>=0)?f([...r,a[0]]):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY0xDoMwDEX3nsJbYrVEsFIZDmJ5iFKoQEAQQVw/DbAhunh473//3m42uKWb12zynybGlixVmt3LGLMIWTTBj43eEnRP2rCiHOtW865flnMRLG1cKVB10iBmtLN2QBWkQwSKFdSQFVBCgXi1iddHpAQlCk3vu0krhQ/np@CHxgz@q1etOEl8X6kI8x1n4aRuG0nd/2LeW6n3Z@mQfO7FHw)

Input array of \$\pm 1\$, output rotated array.

Thanks [user81655](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46855/user81655) for -1 byte.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY0xDoMwDEX3nsJbYrVEsFIZDmJ5iFKoQEAQQVw/DbAhunh473//3m42uKWb12zynybGlixVmt3LGLMIWTTBj43eEnRP2rCiHOtW865flnMRLG1cKVB10iBmtLN2QBWkQwSKFdSQFVBCgXi1iddHpAQlCk3vu0krhQ/np@CHxgz@q1etOEl8X6kI8x1n4aRuG0nd/2LeW6n3Z@mQfO7FHw)

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, 52 bytes

(Sorry if i formatted my answer wrong, i'm brand new here.)

### Golf version

```
a=>{while(t=0,a.some(v=>(t+=v)<0))a.push(a.shift())}
```

### More readable version (and you can try it out)

```js
function rotateArrayUntilBalanced(array) {
  var total; // Create a total variable
  while (total=0,array.some(value => (total += value) < 0)) { // This tests if the array is still unbalanced
    array.push(array.shift()); // Shift array right
  }
}

button.onclick = function () {
  const array = input.value.split('').map(value => (value == '[' ? 1 : -1));
  rotateArrayUntilBalanced(array);
  resultArea.innerText = array.map(value => (value == 1 ? '[' : ']')).join('');
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="brackets go here">
<button id="button">Go</button>
<div id="resultArea"></div>
```

Comment: try it online says `Unexpected token while` here:[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAvzC1UQmjg@UjxqExEDAqRGp9Pt4drNz2J1eZdO49EpP/Uj4DCLmRbStXACUPMpDi4hDZvndLOQqwraUCYo9gttVg/wE "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Your ungolfed version looks cool, but the golfed version doesn't seem to work. I think you need some curly brackets around it.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the problem, and i'ts now 52 bytes. BTW, bytes is just the number of characters, right?

Comment: @asdf3.14159 In most cases, yes. If you're using non-ASCII characters (things you can't type on a US keyboard), there might be extra bytes (for example, `£` (2 bytes) or `™` (3 bytes))

Comment: Also, some golfing languages have their own code pages, known as SBCS's (Single Byte Character System). Basically, this means that any character that would be used in a program is encoded as a single byte - with the drawback that characters outside of the code page cannot be encoded, and including them would mean you would have to score your answer based on a code page that can encode them, like Unicode, possibly adding bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 80 bytes

```r
function(x){while(min(cumsum(92-(y=utf8ToInt(x)))))x=intToUtf8(c(y[-1],y[1]));x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@9CsIwFIV3nyLokoAd6qRI3Z0EqdPlIjW0GLQJtAm2iM9eY5pI0dztnPPdv2ZolC50eb40Bb@Vus2GykiuhZK0Y8/HVdxLWgtJualbU9PNKqF9ZnS1ztVeast8qsuE1Lk6WZty2kOS4rKHFBnbdq/fDXQOOGdkQb6V7AgBnP1xiABT0nGAERLQ2hPWk1HWujC9IEwFJIcjcWFsgxtnI985dgUvdruLIHwQ@NEOm0btldfDGw)

Input is string of square-brackets.
Alternatively, a port of [Leo's Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221300/95126) using a vector of `1`s & `-1`s as input is only [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##rZFPS8QwEMXvfophFyTBrbCedKF79yTIegqhxJiyQZpZk4nWT1/Tv1qht@aUmeT93pvENx5JkSlevdLvhkLelNFpsuhYzTWrdzUXwXwwldf85uts9fm2so7pWIVYpStcNlvQ6D6NJyCEayg9VmBU@M4IM2/UG4xssC5Q28AS9rtsD6ptXSIdrgZCQVigM0WyiCFt8j9hHu6ySOX9CR8dpXKStH6LIuvohC9JxpI8iZZV7N9DsIVIbCPkhnMOW5hWdgQQcg22lELM6R1bSLlO8gSa8Qf6SvzEEfPXGdMLCU/P0B2vM0kXOsEmt95p7K7zFx1M/P7I6NEfjBP19VANdfMD).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:min(sum(a[:i])for i in range(len(a)))<0and f([a.pop()]+a)or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYrBCsIwEETvfsUedzGVBm9Fv6TkMKWNBppNiPXg18e0Bw/CMAPvTf5sz6TXWv19RZxmEIYYlF/vyBiH4MSnQoGCUoE@Fl4XZYjIrYfO5HnEJafM4s6Q9kTNJejGTVhDnXUipx/pDmRoz7@w5qh9mqpf)

Takes input as a list of 1s and -1s, with 1 denoting `[` and -1 denoting `]`.

For a valid bracket sequence, no prefix of the array will have a sum less than 0, so if the current array is not a valid bracket sequence, rotate it by 1 and try again.

*-2 bytes thanks to tsh*

Comment: `[:i+1]` -> `[:i]`

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 74 bytes

```javascript
a=>eval("try{Function(a.replace(/]/g,'-1]'));a}catch{f(a.slice(1)+a[0])}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BDoMgFET3PYYbIK1a1waXXuKHxQ9FS0PAADVpjGen1O4aup03b@aBKwbp9RJr624qTTwhH9SKhlbRv7bxaWXUzlJsvFoMSkVb0c4XUneCMNbjLjHK@zblQjA6446dEa6C7RVLkQc@TDSw/iSdDc6oxriZRkrgsH9TIQBKOQjIqGhkVN4C@FjZ@/N0QPj@pTc)

Convert each `]` to `-1]`, and try to check if there are any syntax error...

This is ES2019.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda a:min((sum(a[:i]),a[i:]+a[:i])for i in range(len(a)))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBDoIwEETvfsXeuo1oQrw16Zese1gj6BooBOrBr68FjAGO82bm9Z/47MIl1f6aGmlvdwFxrQbE8d2ikFO2hZA6Pi6h7gZQ0ACDhEeFTRVQrLVUcor@ZxidMedXly2G2JCC93AqGf7fGonKYmJLadis2pGtPfSDhohxNqwjM5HZ9pTZdpPZ7kY07fJyb5spzc70BQ)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(v=>(++i,c+=v)<m?0:o=[...a.slice(i),...a.slice(0,i,m=c)],i=c=m=0)&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY0xDoMwDEX3niITiUWIYKV1OIiVIUqhCgKCGsT1aaBLhehiyf/5@fd2tdG9/bwUU3i2W4ebRW3VaGexohZ57qXLcYXH2JR1QFJKWRUH71rhQf5spfRyRAdGenQ4YglZFrYFI@pO7Fo0x1fHULM0EBknzhpWVKxmFcCZprw5TmrGDQfVBz8JzuHmwhTD0KohvMQiOCUI93NqDNFVToYSujQSuv5FtFvJ@9N0QPr2bR8)

Input an array of \$\pm 1\$.

Count each `[` as \$-1\$, each `]` as \$+1\$. Find out the position \$p\$ where \$\sum_{i=0}^{p}a_i\$ has max value. And rotate it there. I believe this approach may be golfed more bytes, but I didn't find out an obvious way.

Comment: Sorry that I had to split my previous submission into two post...

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 50 bytes

```
func[s][while[error? try[load s]][move s tail s]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY09DsIwDIX3nsLKzgUY4A6sTx7SxFEjlaZyAqinDy6o4Mnf@9FTif0mETykM/X0WAIq4zXlWSCqRa/UdMNcfKTKjHt5ClVqPs/GlXsqKj5MNBIGsnNg930sDXdoMDp0o18I2D1z/60PY@8yVs1LQyjrZgPudHGUaGTubw)

#### Explanation

[Red](http://www.red-lang.org) uses brackets for its `block!` datatype so every set of balanced brackets is a valid   value. That's why I'm trying to load the string holding the brackets (that is to convert the string to a Red value) and if this throws an error, I move the leading character of the string at the tail.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

*-2 thanks to [@Command Master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master).*

```
ηOWk>._
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Hb/8Gw7vfj//6N1DXUUQBhBGcYCAA) Takes input as a list, with `1` for `[` and `-1` for `]`.

```
ηOWk>._  # full program
     ._  # rotate...
         # implicit input...
     ._  # left...
    >    # 1...
   k     # -based index of...
  W      # maximum...
η        # cumulative...
 O       # sum...
η        # of...
         # implicit input...
   k     # in...
η        # cumulative...
 O       # sums...
η        # of...
         # implicit input...
     ._  # times
         # implicit output
```

`>._` can also be `._À` with no change in functionality.

As a bonus, this works too!

```
ηOWk>

._.
```

Comment: `Å»+}` -> `ηO` for -2

Comment: @CommandMaster Oh yeah! However, shouldn't that be a 4 byte save since ηO code should be put in its place? :P

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>110</s> 108 bytes

```javascript
x=>{for(s=x,i=0;++i<x.length;s=s.slice(1)+s[0])for(y=0,h=s;++y<s.length;h=h.replace('[]',''))if(!h)return s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBDsIgEADAr@gJCJXUc7t@hHAgdVswhG1YNG2Mb8d6cM7z8C/PU4lrvWS6YyNoG9zeMxXJsHUR@kHrOG4mYV5qGBjYcIoTyqvSbHunfnWHvgvAR91H/tcAwRRckz@ysE50QigVZ3kOqmB9lnziT5soMyU0iRZJUjhnnbXHa18)

This was very tricky, but I managed to abuse for loops a lot.

Explained:

```javascript
x=>{                      // declare function
  for(                    //repeat:
    s=x,i=0;              //initiate string and looper to 0
    ++i<x.length;         //repeat while i+1 is less than string length, and increment i at the same time
    s=s.slice(1)+s[0]     // loop string along by 1
  )
    for(                  //repeat:
      y=0,h=s;            //initiate looper, and string to use to check if matching
      ++y<s.length;       //repeat while incremented y is less than string length (since there are only so many brackets)
      h=h.replace('[]','')// remove a single occurrence of [] from h - if this is repeated enough and brackets match, it will eventually be empty.
)
if(!h)return s           // if h is an empty string, this means s's brackets match, so return s. No point in dealing with invalid input since it will always be valid.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.rotate (0..s.size).min_by{|r|s[0,r].sum}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxLCsMwDESv4k0ggUYkq67aiwhRLHAgi7TBciiu5bO7SruZzxuYeHBuy62NdykC8ZV8Cq6fAARk/YQBtvX54Fw0quB0iQRybLW23XXvHskRITokNHemaAjx7EbO9ZeM2JHfi3pd0APnFOQPWOeRu2ul2r4)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 56 bytes

```javascript
q=>q.map(async _=>q.push(q.shift())|eval(q+'')|alert(q))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxbDoMgEEX/XUX/mElTNtDgRiakEopVQ0EETZq4d4rGPv7uua9BLSrqqR/Txfm7ycqaKQktau1d9NZw6x@g@eB71zR4rVqRg6gDf6oRVHw5fbptOM6xg8Bj17cJEFezKAvhzBiu@yMExJxEFHULxDmPEqsEjCQrn0VISXRIklTo4xf6loi2rKS/1c70tz3q@Q0)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (Kona)](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 13 bytes

```
{(1+*>+\x)!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoAgDAXQ3VPULorEGFZM9CC1g4uQkOhKQjg7FnTq/@83zOG5z1Ium0ajp00fUfUxF2fTbDQSMO6LjbnzdmzNaNUlDxc4iHkQY1wBmYnqJSaJTSR@G1FV8f@zFUFU5QU)

Uses -1 for [ and 1 for ].

A port of [Adám's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221310/75681)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
(.*?)(((<)|(?<-4>>))+)$
$2$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZIQHZtgY/dfQ0/LXlNDQ8NGs0bD3kbXxM5OU1NbU4VLxUjF8H8IUAVQ3f/oWK7Y2OhorujYaCDNBSSjgULR0SA@UAQkC2YBRQA) Takes input as a string of `<`s and `>`s but link includes test suite which maps `[` and `]` for convenience. Explanation: This is a fairly direct application of .NET balancing groups. The `<` character is captured into group `$4`, which works like a stack. Meanwhile, `>` characters can only be matched by popping `<`s from the `$4` stack. This ensures that we take the first suffix of the input that does not contain a mismatched `>`. (It can of course have a mismatched `<` but that will be matched by a `>` in the prefix.) It then remains to exchange the prefix with the suffix.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/)  < 7 -F, 59 bytes

```php
for($a=$argn;eval($a)!==null;)$a=substr($a,1).$a[0];echo$a;
```

[Try it online! (not working, PHP 7)](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSbVUSi9LzrFPLEnOAPE1FW9u80pwca02gTHFpUnEJSI2OoaaeSmK0Qax1anJGvkqi9f//tbW11SBYXf0vv6AkMz@v@L@uGwA)

[Try with onlinephpfunctions (working PHP 5.6)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ae2ca44e65132d5718163fd5da26656281ae574)

Inspired by [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221299/90841). Works with `{}` braces instead of square ones.

[From the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> eval() returns null unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned. As of PHP 7, if there is a parse error in the evaluated code, eval() throws a ParseError exception. Before PHP 7, in this case eval() returned false and execution of the following code continued normally.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 89 bytes

This solution uses parenthesis rather than brackets.

```powershell
for($n=$args){try{$n-replace"\(",",@("|iex *>0;break}catch{$n=-join$n[1..$n.Length+0]}}$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1da8IwFIbv@yuknM2TWUu9lozArgaDCrvsitR4anVdWtIUN2J@e5fIpnfvc96P03dn0kNDbTtBze1UdxpBcaj0YWDW6B8LaqmpbytJ8QfGSZwIjC9H@p49PWfrnabq08nKyMYH@fLUHRWoYpWmoNI3UgfTLLLSOVCTi8BILjASOEc2Z0kQjCH@SWTo6f/u6RZCDJ53760rY@hGLAJNgx9m4cHlwQZc8GLz/jIOpvvKdyeSpixyvSdN@1LYV9WPhsO2yMp1PpoA@Aj1TGyZc9e16Rc)

### Bonus [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), Regex-Based <sup><strike>129</strike></sup> 127 bytes

Sure, the other way is shorter, but how often do I get a chance to use my balanced-bracket-matching regex?? Almost never!

```powershell
for($n=$args;!($n-match'((\[(?=[^\]]*(?<s>\]))|\k<s>(?<-s>))+?(?(s)(?!)))*'-and$n-eq$Matches[0])){$n=-join$n[1..$n.Length+0]}$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BT4NAEIXv/AqbrLJThNRzu4XEk4kGE4/D2iAspbVd6u4SD5TfjrNN1dv75s17M6fuWxnbqsNhYo0YpqYznGnBSrO1yxnJ@Fi6qg05L5CnAt8LKec8Xdl1IQHOxScpwtiuAaKUp9wCT2cAMA/jUteUV1/sxVcoiwuKDNQe77udZhofkoTp5FnprWujhRyZnsaAuUpkPMh4iDKEey@kRLxKlEj0Oyf6W0L0Hrn/qQujzwYQMKMsFYM/cL4dPEYCX98ee@u6Y/6xV5WTmJtaGVXLbHjSp94JtqGvl3nvPPA71txkGxjHS9v0Aw)

Comment: Your regex is much longer than it needs to be: `for($n=$args;$n-notmatch'^((\[)|(?<-2>]))*$'){$n=-join$n[1..$n.Length+0]}$n` suffices. `$args-match'((\[)|(?<-2>]))*$'` actually returns the longest suffix, but I don't know enough PowerShell to append the prefix.

Comment: nice `*>0`. Very smart with splatting!

Comment: nice `$n-replace *>0`. but `$e=$n-replace` is shorter :)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

Inspired by [Zaelin Goodman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221331/80745)

```powershell
param($n)$n|% t*y|%{($n=($n|% S*g 1)+$n[0])}|?{try{$_-replace'\(',',(0'|iex;1}catch{}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDNboMwEITvfgorcup1SqTkjFAj9dRTqnKkKKJm81MRQo1RExk/OzVgqE8zs/vNSq5uv6jqMxZFx46R6apMZVdgpWBlu6R69WiXxtkIBh@vTnQrnlmZbFJh2xej1cOww1phVWQS@SfwgAew4e0F7@HWykzLs7G2s4TsgJAAOAhO/Qto70SfCgHA/1MQPgfh5DgZ83niFPiuoWdgPDu1wgC4wE9m528O1sV8bOjltOs1zOS47EgiqPsJQwirtbqUp4DhvUKpMacRZQfCFNZNoWvnntiR@i2SvMevTa1v1/3Xt9tOk73KUWGe7kzcSIl1DywmeEHX@OPsVL0I6VtZNbo/MRaG9GO@M1Hul233Bw)

The script returns all solutions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
{:k[øo|Ǔ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B%3Ak%5B%C3%B8o%7C%C7%93&inputs=%27%5D%5D%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5B%5B%27&header=&footer=)

Takes as a string of `[]`.

```
{        # While...
    øo   # Removing until no change...
  k[     # The string `[]`
 :       # From the top of stack
    øo   # Eventually yields a truthy value (i.e. non-balanced)
      |Ǔ # Rotate left.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 147 bytes

```python
def f(u):
 k=set()
 for x in permutations(u):
  s=''.join(x)
  try:eval(s)
  except:pass
  else:k.add(s)
 print "\n".join(k)
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxDsMgDEX3nMJiiemQoSNSbtIFNUalSTACt0pOTyFpu/n5vR93eXC4ljKRA4cvbTqYx0yCugPHCTbwASKl9SVWPId8NpDHvh@e7ANutQRJu6G3XTA3ou1OUUy0OTdaMpl5sNN02Jh8EFC3oM79rDuXeAUvlIR5yeDXyEkuxaFCrapGpTXieaHGCt9vhV@B2Ex1/8WB2HblAw)

Slow, permutation based approach

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to check all permutations, only rotations.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
≔Ｅθ⁻№…θκ[№…θκ]η⭆θ§θ⁺κ⌕η⌊η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DN7FAo1BHwTczr7RYwzm/NK9Ew7kyOSfVOSMfLJGtqaOgFK0EJHFJxippagLpDE1rroCiTKCS4BIglQ412LHEMy8ltQLEDMgBWpGto@CWmZeikQG2MzO3NFcjQxMMrP//j42NjQbB6Oj/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅθ⁻№…θκ[№…θκ]η
```

Calculate the imbalance between `[`s and `]`s for every prefix.

```
⭆θ§θ⁺κ⌕η⌊η
```

Switch the prefix with the greatest imbalance with its suffix.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 131 bytes

```
=LET(s,LEN(A1),x,SEQUENCE(s),y,INDEX(SORTBY(MOD(x,s),MMULT((x>=TRANSPOSE(x))*1,(MID(A1,x,1)="[")*2-1)),1),MID(A1,y+1,s)&LEFT(A1,y))
```

Converts brackets to 1, -1; finds the minimum cumulative sum y; then moves the first y characters to the end.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 123 bytes

`[n:=range(l:=len(s)),next(r for i in n if [r:=(2*s)[i:i+l],min(sum("]-[".index(c)-1 for c in r[:p]) for p in n)][1]>=0)][1]`

**Takes in string of square brackets. Should return first valid rotation:**

```
>>> s="]][][["
>>> [n:=range(l:=len(s)),next(r for i in n if [r:=(2*s)[i:i+l],min(sum("]-[".index(c)-1 for c in r[:p]) for p in n)][1]>=0)][1]
'[][[]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>11</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Uses `1` for `[` & `0` for `]`.

```
ÈeA}f@éY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&header=cidbJzEgciddMA&code=yGVBfWZA6Vk&footer=VnIxJ1sgcjAnXQ&input=Il1dXVtdW11bW1si) - header converts input from brackets and footer converts back to brackets.

```
ÈeA}f@éY     :Implicit input of string U
È            :Left function taking a string as argument
 e           :Recursively replace
  A          : "10"
   }         :End function
    f        :Return the first result of the right function that returns falsey (empty string) when passed through the left function
     @       :Right function with argument Y, 0-based Iteration index
      éY     :  Rotate U right Y times
```